# JavaScript for multiple image change based on pc clock

Tags: javascript, image, timer, clock

I am just learning JavaScript and doing a course in web design so im new but I need to have ten images that change every 5 minutes independently. each one will change every 5 minutes according to the pc clock between 3 images and loop back to the first.

I have been trying to achieve this using set interval.

I am getting confused when it comes to laying out the JavaScript as I can only get the last image of the ten to do what I need, when I need all ten to do what I need.

```
var start = new Date().getTime(),
    i = 0,
    //get the node of the image to change
    img = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG')[0]; 

setInterval(function(){
    //what time is now
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    if(now - start > 60000){
        //initialize the counter
        start = now;
        //overlay with 0's -> substr(-4)
        //rotate on 1440 with a modulo -> i++ % 1440
        img.src = ('000' + (i++ % 1440 + 1)).substr(-4)  + '.jpg';
    }
}, 10000); //check every 10 sec
```

I found this but cant get more than one image working

Comment: What is confusing about set interval?  Have you defined a function that will run after the interval?

Comment: The trouble I am having is getting all 10 work. It tends to just be the last image that works but the other 9 seem as if the js skips them

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
document.getElementsByTagName(...)
```

returns a list of elements.  Your code is selecting only the first one and setting the "img" variable to that one.  Modify the "setInterval" function to handle an array instead of a single element and set "img" to the full array instead of a single element and it should work:

```
 img = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
```

Comment: If you would like more specific help with how to handle javascript arrays or other questions on how to do this, please comment with specific requests.